# hair doesn't follow the mixamo character help!

Tags: animation, particles, armature, hair, dynamic

I just have a problem because when I had hair dynamics to my mixamo armature, the hair suddenly don't move along with the character. And as you can see in the modifiers, the particule system is below the armature, so I don't understand what is wrong.  [image][image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score -4):

you should put particles hair on the mesh ,not armature

Comment: While this may be a correct solution, it's not completely clear what you mean. Do you mean re-order the modifiers? Could you flesh this answer out with an illustration of the settings, or a toy example? Assume we know nothing :)